# Weird numbers in generated CSV with Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, oracle, csv, spring-batch

I am developing a Spring batch to get data from a table and into a CSV file. This is the table I am extracting data from:

```
CREATE TABLE TMP_SYNCHRONIZED_RSLT
(SERIAL_QA NUMBER(20) UNIQUE
, NB_RECENT VARCHAR2(10)
, NB_ARTICLE VARCHAR2(2)
);
```

I have my reader as follows:

```
<bean id="serialNumbersReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="fetchSize" value="${batch.job.fetch.interval}" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper">
            <property name="mappedClass" value="ca.org.serialNumbersGenerationBatch.batch.synchronization.dto.ExtractSerialNumbersDto" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="sql">
        <value>
            <![CDATA[
                SELECT SERIAL_QA, NB_RECENT, NB_ARTICLE from TMP_SYNCHRONIZED_RSLT
            ]]>
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And my writer:

```
    <bean id="csvWriteSerialNumbers" 
class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
        <property name="lineAggregator">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
                <property name="delimiter" value=";" />
                <property name="fieldExtractor">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                        <property name="names" value="serialQa, nbRecent, nbArticle" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="encoding" value="${csv.encoding}" />
        <property name="headerCallback">
            <bean class="fr.canalplus.cgaweb.batch.common.writer.StringHeaderFooterCallback">
                <property name="header" value="SERIAL_QA;NB_RECENT;NB_ARTICLE" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="resource" value="file:${tmp.dir}/serialNumbers.csv" />
    </bean>
```

my csv.encoding = ISO-8859-1. And I put String in all of my DTO attributes.
This generates weird numbers like 2,49254E+12 instead of 24925418071 in my CSV under SERIAL_QA. Any idea on how to resolve this without changing the column type?

Comment: @APC I use Excel

Comment: That's probably your problem. By default Excel renders very large numbers using scientific notation. Try changing the column's formatting and you'll see the actual numbers are there.

Comment: @APC it does work but is there a way to configure the column type ahead? When the FileWriter creates it?

Comment: Is Excel the target usage for these files? In which case you should use something which writes XLSX format not CSVs. But I know nothing about Spring or Spring-batch so I can't advise you on that.

Comment: @APC, yes Excel is the target usage for these files but I generate the files in CSV format.

Comment: I'm afraid that's your dilemma. CSV is a plain text format. There's no way to encode Excel commands in a CSV file. So, either you use a different writer which can produce XLSX files or you have to live with how Excel handles CSV. Maybe defining a template (XLT) file could solve your problem?